# List of keywords for title/person/character objects?

Tags: python-2.7, imdb, imdbpy

Is there a list of keywords that can be used?

I.e.: in the examples in the docs, it has `print item['long imdb canonical title'], item.movieID`

Where is a list of the keywords for indexes in the data (like "['long imdb canonical title']") and  a list of attributes (like ".movieID")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IMDbPY objects emulate the behavior of dictionaries, so you can get the list of its keys with: item.keys() and introspect it to get its attributes: dir(item)